# Rogue $_GET input key added in laravel 5 production environment

Tags: php, post, laravel, nginx, laravel-5

I'm having a really strange issue. I have an app that is working perfectly in my local environment, and was recently working in production just fine. Now though, in production, it is adding a rogue backslash key to my input. It shows up in `Input::all()` but not in `$_POST`. I'm using the following code to debug.

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('/', function() {
    return [
        '$_FILES' => $_FILES,
        '$_GET' => $_GET,
        '$_POST' => $_POST,
        'Input::all()' => Input::all()
    ];
});
```

---

**Response**

```
{
  "$_FILES": [],
  "$_GET": {
    "\\": ""
  },
  "$_POST": {
    "start_date": "2015-02-17",
    "end_date": "2015-02-23",
    "name": "Test Data"
  },
  "Input::all()": {
    "start_date": "2015-02-17",
    "end_date": "2015-02-23",
    "name": "Test Data",
    "\\": ""
  }
}
```

---

### Additional Details

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns a path like `/example/path` with nothing unusual in it.

Comment: Did you try print_r $_GET, $_POST, $_FILES ?
May be your production server add this parameters ?

Comment: At first I suggest to update to the newest version of Laravel.

Comment: @MartirosAghajanyan — Good call! Looks like it is in a `$_GET` param

Comment: @lukasgeiter — I've updated to the latest with and without `"minimum-stability": "dev"`

Comment: Are the slashes present if you print_r($_GET) outside or Laravel?

Comment: @Dave — Yes. It sure is. So it must be a configuration issue. I'm running nginx with a straight-forward host file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this was an nginx-related issue. I'm not sure why it seemed to appear suddenly, but I was able to replace the following block in my nginx host file to solve the issue.

**Broken version**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

---

**Working version** (copied from another config that was laying around)

```
location ~ \.php$ {

    # Security risk mitigation
    try_files $uri =404;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 360;

    # added these from tmberg's recommedation (on freenode)
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;

    # connect to FPM on a unix socket
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /www/mydomain.com/public$fastcgi_script_name;

    # Added to allow for larger error headers to output
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 10m;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 512k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 512k;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 512k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_next_upstream error invalid_header timeout http_500;

}
```